# How to create checkbox element in htmlunit?

Tags: checkbox, htmlunit

I am trying to use the createElement method explained in the following link:

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/InputElementFactory.html#createElement-com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SgmlPage-java.lang.String-org.xml.sax.Attributes-

For this I am trying to use the following code:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://...");
HtmlCheckBoxInput checkBox = (HtmlCheckBoxInput) page.createElement("checkbox");
```

But the createElement method returns an HtmlUnknownElement object. How can I create the checkbox element?

The following code is working while creating an input text element:

```
HtmlElement tmpCheckBox = (HtmlElement) pageClientInput.createElement("input");
```

Following the suggestion given here I have tried this other way:

```
HtmlElement tmpInput = (HtmlElement) page.createElement("input");
tmpInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
HtmlRadioButtonInput  tmpCheckBox = (HtmlRadioButtonInput) tmpInput;
tmpCheckBox.setChecked(true);
```

But I am getting an exception casting the HtmlElement to HtmlRadioButtonInput:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlRadioButtonInput
```

I need an HtmlRadioButtonInput in order to use the setChecked method. HtmlElement  doesn't have setChecked method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wont work because HtmlPage.createElement can't choose the correct Element Factory without attributes. Which you cannot set through this method.

You can access the correct element factory through InputElementFactory and setting the type as checkbox, as below.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://...");

    //Attribute need to decide the correct input factory
    AttributesImpl attributes = new org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl();
    attributes.addAttribute(null, null, "type", "text", "checkbox");
    // Get the input factory instance directly or via HTMLParser, it's the same object 
    InputElementFactory elementFactory = com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory.instance; // or HTMLParser.getFactory("input")
    HtmlCheckBoxInput checkBox = (HtmlCheckBoxInput) elementFactory.createElement(page, "input", attributes);
    // You need to add to an element on the page
    page.getBody().appendChild(checkBox);
    //setChecked like other methods return a new Page with the changes
    page = (HtmlPage) checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your createElement call produces an HtmlUnknownElement because there is not checkbox html tag. To create a checkbox you have to create an input with type 'checkbox'.

Start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox) to read more about html and checkboxes.

Comment: I have tried the way you have suggested but it's not working, I have edited my question if you want to check de details. Thanks.